# Add value in datagrid cell after value of combobox is selected c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to create an application which outputs a simple text file. This is my first project in c#. I have created a data grid table. There are basically 5 cells in each row ,and the rows are added dynamically after the user input. User can change values in 2 of the 5 cells only. 
My problem lies here,
In the third cell user has to select a value from combo box in cell 3, the values in cell 4 and 5 are to be populated after the value in combo box is selected. However I am unable to do that. 
Attached is the image for reference.[image: application image]

Comment: If you want to act immediately when selection changed then capture `SelectionChanged` event of the respective combobox. or you want to react when user selects a value and presses enter key handle `CellValueChanged` event

Comment: I want to act immediately when selection is changed in combo box, being said that there's one more doubt I have how would I understand in which row has the value of combo box changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
//EditingControlShowing event handler for your dataGridView1
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e){
   ComboBox combo = e.Control as ComboBox;
   if(combo != null) combo.SelectedIndexChanged += GridComboSelectedIndexChanged;
}
private void GridComboSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   ComboBox combo = sender as ComboBox;
   //Your populating code here
   //you can access the selected index via combo.SelectedIndex
   //you can access the current row by dataGridView1.CurrentCell.OwningRow
   //then you can access to the cell 4 and cell 5 by dataGridView.CurrentCell.OwningRow.Cells[4] and dataGridView.CurrentCell.OwningRow.Cells[5]
}
```

Comment: As I understand from the code what it does is, when the user selects combo box in the table, the code will be populated.
I tried with this code, I applied a break point in the function `private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing` but the execution never passed from the function, can you tell me what might ahve gone wrong??

Comment: @vin have you registered the event handler `dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing`? In the case you don't know how, you have to add this line first (in your form constructor) `dataGridView1.EditingControlShowing += dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing;`